# Why do I get an error trying to use keras package in R?

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to run through an example for building a neural network in R. I tried following the instructions at https://opendatascience.com/using-keras-and-tensorflow-in-r/.
I've installed the keras and tensorflow packages and I have the anaconda navigator downloaded on my laptop. When I run the following:

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
reticulate::use_condaenv(“r-reticulate”)
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
```

I'm getting this error

```
Error in conda_python(envpath, conda = miniconda) : 
  no conda environment exists at path 'C:/Users/smurphy4/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate'
```

This is probably a stupid question but I haven't used python before and I only have a little experience with R and would really appreciate any help.

Also, I don't know if this is relevant but when I open the anaconda navigator and look in environments, there isn't an r-reticulate environment, only a base (root) environment.[Anaconda navigator environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1f5u.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has a similar problem, I just uninstalled Rstudio and installed again through a new python environment in anaconda navigator and installed the modules I needed in that environment. That seemed to work.